# (How) can I create mulitple variables in R similar as easily as in Stata (foreach loop) when working with panel data?

Tags: r, loops, wildcard, stata, panel-data

When working with panel data in Stata it is possible to create and modify multiple variables at once like this:

```
foreach wave of numlist 1/7 {
    clonevar vote`wave' = kp`wave'_190ab
    replace vote`wave' = 8 if v_intention`wave' == 0
}
```

In a first step this command simply copies and renames the variables `kp1_190ab`, `kp2_190ab` etc. to `vote1`, `vote2` etc. The next step is a simple `replace` command that is dependent on other variables (`v_intention1` to `v_intention7`).

Is it possible to create loops in R that do things like that? In Stata it is very useful that the wildcard `x' can be used, but I couldn't find something like that in R.

Comment: Use a list (or data.frame) to hold your variables. It's very easy to iterate over these, e.g., with `lapply` loops.

Comment: This is easy to advise but hard to act on. Beyond the obvious, few constructs in R are close, one-to-one matches of those in Stata, or vice versa. There is shared ancient history in Fortran and C, but R and Stata have had 30+ years to diverge. The same problem often call forth very different ways of thinking  and very different syntax. Even on a minor level I know that commands in Stata I first wrote were often informed by what was nearest in S [NB], but one-to-one translations were often neither possible nor especially appropriate given the rest of Stata's syntax and structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[` is what you are looking for.
Here is a direct translation using no additional packages.

```
## DF is your data frame
for (wave in 1:7) {
    newvar <- paste0('vote',wave)
    DF[[newvar]] <- DF[[paste0('kp',wave,'_190ab')]]
    DF[DF[[paste0('v_intention',wave)]]==0, newvar] <- 8
}
```

You can make it shorter using `ifelse`, `apply`, etc., but the same idea. I would code it as:

```
f <- function(DF,srcfmt,wave,tstfmt) {
    srcvar <- sprintf(srcfmt, wave)
    tstvar <- sprintf(tstfmt, wave)
    ifelse(DF[[tstvar]] == 0, 8, DF[[srcvar]])
}
for (wave in 1:7) {
    DF[[paste0('vote',wave)]] <- f(DF,'kp%d_190ab',wave, 'v_intention%d')
}
```

Above `f` can be written on one long line.

Without a data frame (`DF`) it is hard but you can still do it using `get` and `assign`. For example, `assign(sprintf("b%d",4), get(sprintf("a%d",4)))` is equivalent to `b4 <- a4`. Implementing it as a function without a data frame will involve environments (`?environment`) and you will hate it. It is a lot simpler to have all contained in a data frame.

Comment: Do not use assign for this. That approach would make everything more difficult than necessary. If for some reason you are allergic to lists, you can use [[ on environments.

Comment: @chan1142 I used your answer, but then noticed that it is even easier to just do it this way, without having to write a function:
`for (wave in 1:7) {
   data[[paste0('vote',wave)]] <- data[[paste0('kp',wave,'_190ba')]]
  data[[paste0('vote',wave)]][data[[paste0('wahlabs',wave)]]==0] <- 8
} `